# Performance navigation view lagging

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I have a layout that includes about 8 linear layout each with 5 buttons, my problem is that I am having a navigation view as well and whenever I open it or close it lags very much.

I tried removing the 8 linear layouts and it works fine, so I think it's because these layouts are being recalculated whenever I open or close the drawer, is there a way I can avoid this?

I tried using only one relative layout instead of these 8 linear layout and than position the buttons with respect to each other, the performance improved but still lags a little bit.

Is there any better approach for performance to align 5 buttons in like 8 rows like a table better than relative layout or linear layout?

Comment: Is this something you can use a ListView for?

Comment: @ McAdam331 no ,its like a keyboard ,it must be all visible in the screen

Comment: use handler to set layout if possible.

Comment: @androidnoobdev i didn't understand ,what do you mean?

Comment: Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

       // set your layout initialization code here and check


    }
});

Try this code

Comment: How about a recycler view with gridlayout manager, that would be way efficient

Comment: @androidnoobdev the app lags when opening the navigation drawer or closing it not when not when initialization the layout for the first time

Comment: @Seaskyways but i need all of views to be visible always not scrolling them

Comment: @has19 yes i am trying to tell you same thing use handler for initializing data for navigation drawer. you may be displaying user image from server and that thing may be causing lags for opening drawer.

Comment: @androidnoobdev the problem isn't with the navigation view ,its with the the fragment that contains 8 linear layout ,my navigation view consists of few static menu item ,if i change the fragment to another layout with only few buttons it works very well and doesn't lag

Comment: Ahh i see , I'm sorry i maybe can't help

Comment: @has19 first test and tell me where is problem, in above comment you told me lag in drawer open and close event and now telling problem in fragment. check it properly.

Comment: @androidnoobdev check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096982/navigation-drawer-animation-is-lagging-while-closing i have the same problem

Comment: @androidnoobdev i found the problem it was because i was setting the alpha for each button ,the performance improved a lot after i removed alpha from it but i have no idea why alpha would cause performance problem in the first place